# How can I implement resume/pause audio recording in Android?

Tags: android, audio, mobile, record

I am building Android app that is doing m4a recording with resume/pause functionality.
Is is possible? If yes then let me know solutions.

Thanks

Comment: "I am building Android app" ... great, share what you have so far.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to play audio/video resources you can use MediaPlayer object, you can wrap it if you have particular needs.Specially, for displaying a video you'll need a SurfaceView and it's holder. Anyway, it works something like this:

Suppose your media resources are on the raw folder, the media player can be something like this:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;

public class MyPlayer {

    private MediaPlayer mPlayer;
    private SurfaceHolder mSurfaceHolder;

    public void play(Context c) {

        if (mPlayer == null) {

            mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(c, R.<YOUR RESOURCE NAME>);
            mPlayer.setDisplay(mSurfaceHolder);

            //Sets a listener to the mPlayer variable that set's it to null once the playing is finished
            mPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                        stop();
                }
            });

        }
        mPlayer.start();
    }

    public void pause() {
        if (mPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            mPlayer.pause();
        }
    }

    public void stop() {
        if (mPlayer != null) {
            mPlayer.release();
            mPlayer = null;
        }
    }

    public void setSurface(SurfaceHolder sh) {
      mSurfaceHolder = sh;
    }

}
```

The player will be incapsulated inside a fragment/activity. Suppose to have a xml layout with a SurfaceView as a "screen" and three buttons for media control, your fragment would be like:

```
public class PlayerFragment extends Fragment {

    private Button mPlayButton;
    private Button mPauseButton;
    private Button mStopButton;
    private SurfaceView mSurface;
    private SurfaceHolder mHolder;
    private MyPlayer mPlayer = new MyPlayer();

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        //Gets the view and sets the player to be able to play a video resource
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.<YOUR XML LAYOUT>, parent, false);
        mSurface = (SurfaceView) v.findViewById(R.id.surface);
        mHolder = mSurface.getHolder();
        mHolder.setKeepScreenOn(true);
        mPlayer.setSurface(mHolder);

        //Inflates the play button and sets on it a listener (created as an anonymous class)
        mPlayButton = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.playButton);
        mPlayButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            mPlayer.play(getActivity());    
            }
        });

        //Inflates the pause button and sets on it a listener (created as an anonymous class)
        mPauseButton = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.pauseButton);
        mPauseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mPlayer.pause();    
            }
        });

        //Inflates the stop button and sets on it a listener (created as an anonymous class)
        mStopButton = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.stopButton);
        mStopButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            mPlayer.stop(); 
            }
        });

        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mPlayer.stop();
    }




}
```

Always be careful and release the media resources once you've finished with them or when the activity/fragment is destroyed since you obtain a lock. If you don't, you could compromise other apps or the OS behavior.

Obviously, if you need more complex features you'll have to add them. This is just an example of a really simple player. Keep also in mind that possible incompatibilities could rise with some sort of files and or devices.

Comment: Thanks for your help, At this moment, I need audio recording function.(pause/resume, play)